# Finding out the version of Dojo

Tags: dojo, internet-explorer-8

I'm kinda new to Dojo toolkit. There are certain issues which I would like to get enlightened (I googled but I didn't get any appropriate & satisfying answers)

1. I have a dojo.js(Perhaps the uncompressed dojo.js downloaded) in my already running application (Developed by another software developer). How to find out which version of dojo.js he has downloaded and is being used right now? (Its not commented. I checked)
2. a) While I'm trying to run my application in IE-8 (Opening a pop-up on click of a button), I get error which is pointing me to this line of code

   if(dojo.isIE&&window.location.protocol==="file:")
   Note: Its working fine in IE6 but the issue is with IE8 & to be even more specific the JS error is displayed only for the first time when I'm clicking the button.

   b) Is it true that dojo 1.3 & above is the best & stable release for IE8?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Version of DOJO:
   var foo: String=dojo.version.toString();
2. a.You have to find IE8 comptablile version.Check API [DOJO API](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/api/)

   b.Its always advisable to check for documentation ( which unfortunately not do) for these kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time :)
But as you rightly said .. its such a pain to go through the entire documentation for such an issue!!

Answer (score 1):

See the [Dojo 1.3 release notes](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/releasenotes/1.3.html) which state IE8 support.  Dojo generally tries to support the latest browsers at the time of each release.  Dojo is close to releasing 1.5, so you'd be advised to start with the latest version possible.

Comment: Thank you peller.. I will check the release notes :)